Turn a coherent subsheaf into a vector subbundle by blowing up
I have some confusions on reading Narasimhan's paper Hermitian-einstein metrics on parabolic stable bundles. The following statements appears between page 103-104.
Let $E$ be a rank 2 holomorphic vector bundle over a compact complex surface $\bar{X}$, and $D$ is a irreducible smooth divisor. Let $F\to D$ be a line subbundle of $E|_{D}$. Let $V$ be a quotient torsion free subsheaf of $E$. Then $V$ is a line bundle and even more, it is a subbundle of $E$ outside a finite set of points, for simplicity let's assume there is only one singular point $x_{0}\in D$. Suppose further that $V|_{D-x_{0}}=F$. These are the basic settings in the paper.
And then, Narasimhan invoked a theorem of Schwarzenberger says that we can find a smooth surface $q:Y\to \bar{X}$, which is obtianed by successively blowing up points over $x_{0}$ such that the following holds. Let $\{P_{i}\}$ be the irreducible components of the exceptional divisor $S=q^{-1}(x_{0})$; then there exist positive integers $\{m_{i}\}$ such that the canonical map from $q^{*}(V)$ to $q^{*}(E)$ maps $q^{*}(V)$ isomorphically into a line subbundle of $q^{*}(E)\otimes \mathcal{O}(-m_{i}P_{i})$. So far so good.
Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x_{0}$ such that we can find a holomorphic frame $f_{1}, f_{2}$ for $E$ such that $f_{2}|_{D}$ is a local frame for $F\to D$ and find $s$ a holomorphic frame of $V$ on $U$. Then $q^{*}(s)$ is a frame of $q^{*}(V)$(here he didn't mention that it is a holomorphic frame but I think it should be). Since $q^{*}(V)$ is a subbundle of $q^{*}(E)\otimes \mathcal{O}(-m_{i}P_{i})$, then we have $q^{*}(s)=aq^{*}(f_{1})\otimes e_{3}+bq^{*}(f_{2})\otimes e_{3}$ where $e_{3}$ is a holomorphic frame of $\mathcal{O}(-m_{i}P_{i})$.And $a,b$ do not vanish simutaneously at any point in $q^{-1}(U)$. Let $D^{*}$ be the proper transformation of $D$. Due to the facts that $V|_{D-x_{0}}=F$ and $f_{2}|_{D}$ is a local frame for $F\to D$, we have $a|_{D^{*}}=0$. Then he claimed that $b$ has no zero on $D^{*}$ and only finitely maniy zeros on the exceptional divisor.
It is this claim that confused me. In my opinion $q^{*}(s)$ is a holomorphic frame, hence that $a,b$ are holomorpphic functions defined on $q^{-1}(U)$. Then since all the irreducible compoents $P_{i}'s$ are indeed $\mathbb{CP}^{1}$(if I am not intepreting the Schwarzenberger's theorem wrong), $a,b$ should be constant on all of them. So I am curious why he said that $b$ could be zero at some point $x\in S$?

Since O(-mP) is not trivial bundle, e3 can not be defined over the whole P1. So a,b are not defined in the whole P1, then they may not be constant.
